# Я не могу получить ответ из функции по слиянию PDF в библиотеке mPDF

Tags: php, ajax, mpdf

Библиотека mPDF 7 версии.
PHP 7.1

Я хотел объединить несколько PDF в один. И они объединяются.
Но я не получаю ответ в return после работы функции.

```
function updatePDFtoPDF($direct, $pathsPDF)
{
    $directorySite = explode('/app', __DIR__);
    require_once($directorySite[0].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'vendor/autoload.php');
    try {
        $mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8']);
        $mpdf->SetImportUse();

        foreach ($pathsPDF as $item){
            $allPage = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('public/scanInvoice/' . $item);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $allPage; $i++) {
                $mpdf->AddPage();
                $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
                $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
                $mpdf->WriteHTML('');
            }
        }
        $preName = $this->translit('onlyPDF');
        $mpdf->Output($direct.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$preName.'.pdf', 'F');
        return $preName.'.pdf';
    } catch (MpdfException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

$pathsPDF - массив с именами файлов. Если я комментирую foreach и получаю только $pathsPDF[0], то return приходит.
Это HTML загрузки файлов.

```
<div class="file-loading">
    <input id="imgInvoice" name="imgInvoice[]" type="file" multiple>
</div>
```

Отправляю через AJAX.

```
var formData = new FormData();
$.each($('#imgInvoice')[0].files, function(key, value) {
    formData.append('file[]', value);
});
$.ajax({
   url: urlOne, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   data: formData,
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   }});
```

Дальше обрабатываю.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
   $success = null;
   $preExt = $paths = $pathspdf = [];
   $filenames = $_FILES['file']['name'];

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($filenames); $i++) {
        $ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
        $fileExt = array_pop($ext);
        $preName = basename($filenames[$i], "." . $fileExt);
        $preName = $this->translit($preName);
        $target = $direct . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $preName . "." . $fileExt;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target)) {
             $success = true;
             if ($fileExt != 'pdf') {
                 $paths[] = '/public/scanInvoice/' . $preName . '.' . $fileExt;
             }
             if ($fileExt == 'pdf') {
                 $pathspdf[] = $preName . '.pdf';
             }
        } else {
             $success = false;
             break;
        }
    }
    if ($success == true) {
        $resultPaths = $this->updatePDFtoPDF($direct, $pathspdf);
        $messageAns = 'успешная отправка';
    }
    $data = [
        'messageAns' => $messageAns,
        'resultPaths' => $resultPaths
    ];
    echo json_encode($data);
    break;
}
```

В итоге в консоле я должен видеть ответ, но его нет.

Comment: Понимаю что кода много и повторить данный пример довольно непросто. Может у кого-то есть другие варианты объединения нескольких PDF файлов в один (ghostscript не предлагать, нет его на сервере).

Comment: Видимо придётся вам использовать отладку чтобы посмотреть что происходит в коде.